# Return json with parent/root node in web api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to return JSON from database table using web api.

Controller

```
private WebApiEntities dataContext = new WebApiEntities();
[ActionName("GetLocations")]
public IEnumerable<Location> GetLocations()
{
    //IEnumerable<Location> list = null;
    var list = (from c in dataContext.LocationMasters
                select new Location
                {
                    LocationId = c.LocationId,
                    LocationName = c.LocationName
                }).ToList();
    return list.OrderBy(c => c.LocationName);
}
```

Location Model :

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string LocationImage { get; set; }
}
```

Can any one help? How to return JSON with parent /node? When I run the above code it displays following output

```
[
    {
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationName": "AMBERNATH",
        "LocationImage": null
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationName": "BHIWANDI",
        "LocationImage": null
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 2,
        "LocationName": "KALYAN",
        "LocationImage": null
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 3,
        "LocationName": "THANE",
        "LocationImage": null
    },
    {
        "LocationId": 4,
        "LocationName": "ULHASNAGAR",
        "LocationImage": null
    }
]
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: from where are you calling this api?

Comment: @CuongLe I want parent node ahead of Json. What are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: @KarthikMR Calling through browser directly.

Comment: What is the parent node is this case?

Comment: can you check in developer tools what is the contenttype value being sent?

Comment: In your question it would be easier if you posted what your expected json output should be.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is something like this

```
{
   "locations": [{
        "LocationId": 5,
        "LocationName": "AMBERNATH",
        "LocationImage": null
        },
        {
         "LocationId": 1,
        "LocationName": "BHIWANDI",
        "LocationImage": null
        }]
}
```

Am I right?

If so the return type of your action cannot be an IEnumerable or array.

What you need to do is return an object with a property containing your array.

```
public object GetLocations()
{
   //IEnumerable<Location> list = null;
   var list = (from c in dataContext.LocationMasters
            select new Location
            {
                LocationId = c.LocationId,
                LocationName = c.LocationName
            }).ToList();
   return new {location = list.OrderBy(c => c.LocationName) };
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I got an InvalidOperationException indicating that a f__AnonymousType4 cannot be serialized.